# Redirecting to default_target_path in custom LoginSuccessHandler?

Tags: symfony

I have a custom success login handler for **custom role-based redirect after successful login**.

When on of these special roles in `$specialRoles` array is found, a new `RedirectResponse` is returned:

```lang-php
/** @DI\Service("handler.login_sucess_handler") */
class LoginSuccessHandler implements uthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "securityContext"= @DI\Inject("security.context"),
     *     "router"         = @DI\Inject("router") })
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext,
        I18nRouter $router)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router          = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request,
        TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $specialRoles = array('ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2', 'ROLE_3');

        foreach($specialRoles as $specialRole)
        {
            if($this->securityContext->isGranted($specialRole))
            {
                $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('manage_index');
                return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, i need to specify **what happens if user has no special roles**. I'd like to make it more flexible, i.e: not hardcoding the default `/app/dashboard` route. That is, read the `default_target_path` (if any) from `security.yml` file:

```
form_login:
    login_path:          /app/login
    check_path:          /app/login_check
    default_target_path: /app/dashboard
    success_handler:     handler.login_sucess_handler
```

Is there any way for doing this?

Of course **leaving the code as is**, when an user hasn't any special role, an exception is thrown:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent::setResponse()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null
>   given.

Comment: Hi. Are you using BeSimpleI18nRouting? If so how do you pass I18nRouting argument to login_success_handler? I have tried someting like this: arguments: [@I18nRouter] but there is no I18nROuting service...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it in one of my projects:

```php
if ($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path')) {
    return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
}
```

Comment: I think that `target_path` is different from `_default_target_path`... am i wrong?

Comment: IIRC, `_security.target_path` is being set to the path the user tried to access before being forced to login or — if it doesn't exist — to `default_target_path` you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add return statement with needed route after `foreach` loop?

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(
        Request $request, 
        TokenInterface $token
    )
    {
        $specialRoles = array('ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2', 'ROLE_3');

        foreach($specialRoles as $specialRole) {
            if ($this->securityContext->isGranted($specialRole)) {
                $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('manage_index');
                return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
            } 
        }

        $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('your_custom_route');
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    }
```

Don't forget to define your custom route in routing, of course.

**EDIT**:

You could also set `_referer` input field in your login form and submit it with your form, and then get it in action by `$request->get('_referer');`

Another way is to try to get referer from headers: `$request->headers->get('Referer');`

And, finally, you could get default target path, which is defined in security.yml: `$request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path');`

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but `referer` header is set when user clicks a link. If user goes directly to the login page, referer is missing, so it can't help. And `_security.target_path` it's not the same as `_default_target_path`...

Comment: I started to write an answer, but found it too complicated to explain. I guess, it would be better to analyze initial implementation: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php#L89

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the redirect problem? These solutions were not working for me at all, but this one:

```
return new RedirectResponse($request->headers->get('Referer'));
```